# HLOOKUP Excel Row Range

Tags: excel

Community, I am going to attempt to explain my situation as best as possible so my question makes sense.  I start off with a single row broken up into a few fields.  If any one of the cells in the first row has a value other than null or "" It duplicates a blank second row.  This is so on and so forth.  The first column in each row has three options.  Pending on which of these three options is selected, should populate the second column accordingly per row.

Example 1 => List 1

Example 2 => List 2

Example 3 => List 3

Currently the second column is set to this list data validation value=$AA:$AA

Each row in AA = =HLOOKUP($A$10,U:W,AB1,FALSE) Where the cell row in AB increments down the list.

Obviously, the issue comes in here.  A10 will always populate B10 properly.  Every row after that B(X) will always populate the same list that A10 populates regardless of what A(X) equals.

I want to know how I can validate each row accordingly to the selection in row A?

Comment: I read it twice... I have no idea what is your problem...

Comment: When someone inserts data into a row, it populates a new row.  Therefor there can be hundreds of rows.  They are all clones of one another.  The first box in each row populates the second box in each row.  There are three lists for the three selection options.  I want to know if there is an easy way to reference those lists in each row.

Answer (score 0):

I added Dependent List Validation.

I needed my three lists, Example 1, Example 2, Example 3

In each cell, I needed to add the following to my validation

=INDIRECT(A10)

=INDIRECT(A11)
and so forth